# How to get the name of the image when clicked in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I want to know the image name whenever image clicked.
i used this code for adding image to button background:

```
ImageBrush brush1 = new ImageBrush();
brush1.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/emptyseat.jpg"));
btn.Background = brush1;
```

now i want to know the name of the image whenever image clicked. please any one help me out.

Comment: Have you tried setting a click-event and then getting the name of the control in the event?

Comment: @fk2 i dnt want to know the name of the control. i want to know which image (name) is added to button.  for example i am using emptyseat.jpg to button. so i want to know this name whenever it is clicked.

Comment: once you are in the event you could just as easily get the image source, get the URI from that and then trim the URI to get the image name...

Comment: @fk2 please  give me sample code

Answer (score 0):

You can save the name in the buttons Tag property

```
ImageBrush brush1 = new ImageBrush();    
brush1.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/emptyseat.jpg"));
btn.Tag = "emptyseat.jpg";
btn.Background = brush1;

public void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var btn = (Button)sender;
    string name = btn.Tag;      
}
```

Comment: I am  trying above code but I am getting this error  "Object eference not set to an instance of an object."   my code is    private async void btnClick_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            string tag = ((Button)sender).Tag.ToString();}

Comment: have you placed any thing in the Tag property ?

Comment: is the sender a button ?

Comment: i'm not gonna go over each token of your code.
debug it and try to understand whats null.